# Sending bulk emails with attachment paths in database

Tags: c#, winforms

I just need help. Basically I am creating a windows appllication that sends bulk emails to our customers.  the field "email" and "attachment" are from database. the attachment field contains only the path where the file is located, The code is working but instead of receiving 5 emails , I receive 15 emails.

Note: my database contain only 5 records , therefore I should receive only 5 emails with attachments:

Can you help me please, Thanks!

Here is my code:

```C#
        string email;
        string attachment;
        ArrayList emailList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList attachList = new ArrayList();
        private static readonly Logger log = new _EventLogger();

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdgetEmail = new SqlCommand("Select EMAIL, PATH from MEMBERREQUIREMENTS WHERE STATUS=0", conn);
            SqlDataReader getEmail = cmdgetEmail.ExecuteReader();
            //count = 0;
            while (getEmail.Read())
            {
                //count++;
                //email = getEmail.GetValue(i).ToString();
                //emailList.Add(email);
                //i = i + 1 - 1;
                email = getEmail.GetString(0);
                emailList.Add(email);
                attachment = getEmail.GetString(1);
                attachList.Add(attachment);
            }
            getEmail.Close();
            conn.Close();
            sendMail();
        }
            private void sendMail()
            {

                string from="myemail@email.com";
                foreach (string sendTo in emailList)
                {

                    foreach (string sendAttachments in attachList)
                    {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(sendTo);
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "Company Name'", Encoding.UTF8);
                    mail.Subject = subject;
                    mail.Body = msgBodyHead + msgBodyHead2 + msgDate + msgGreet + msgBody + msgAdobe + msgAssistance + msgCompliment + msgfooter;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;    
                    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(sendAttachments));

                        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");
                        client.Host = "192.167.89.0";
                        client.EnableSsl = false;
                        try
                        {

                            progress();
                            client.Send(mail);

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ProgressBar1.Visible = false;
                            timer1.Enabled = false;
                            Exception excpt = ex;
                            string errorMessage = string.Empty;

                            while (excpt != null)
                            {

                                errorMessage += excpt.ToString(); excpt = excpt.InnerException;
                                log.Error("Email - LMS Application Error", ex);
                                lblError.Text = "There was an error occured while processing your request.\n Please see Event Viewer for more details.";
                                lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Note that the `[code]` and `[/code]` psuedo-tags mean nothing. The best way to format code is to prepend four spaces to every line. If you select all your code and then hit the `{}` button in the editor, it'll Just Work.

Comment: sorry but the wysywig editor is blocked on our firewall so I cant see it.

Comment: You just need to fix the whitespace before two method names. I tried it myself, but (a) don't have edit priviledges, and (b) that white-space only edit was rejected anyway :(

Comment: @Ergwun: that's unfortunate. Did your change comment include a descriptive enough sentence? (It might also not have been accepted if you retained the "thanks" and "I just need help" bits -- but that's me assuming reasoning behind someone else's actions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're pulling a bunch of records from your `MEMBERREQUIREMENTS` table containing an email address and a path to an attachment, and building a list of e-mail addresses and attachment paths.

You're then iterating over these sending, sending an e-mail for each combination of address and attachment. I'm guessing this is not what you want to do.
I imagine that either:

- each recipient should receive only the attachment listed in their record. In this case, you don't want to iterate over attachments for each address, or possibly
- each recipient should receive each attachment, but the attachments should be listed in a separate table, and not stored in the record for each address in your `MEMBERREQUIREMENTS` table.

**UPDATE:**

Below is some code to do the former. Note that this is just a minimal edit of your posted code, and doesn't fix variable names etc. or provide any additional error checking (which you probably want to do):

```
private static readonly Logger log = new _EventLogger();


private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdgetEmail = new SqlCommand("Select EMAIL, PATH from MEMBERREQUIREMENTS WHERE STATUS=0", conn);
    SqlDataReader getEmail = cmdgetEmail.ExecuteReader();
    while (getEmail.Read())
    {
        email = getEmail.GetString(0);
        attachment = getEmail.GetString(1);
        this.sendMail(email, attachment)
    }
    getEmail.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void sendMail(string sendTo, string sendAttachments)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(sendTo);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "Company Name'", Encoding.UTF8);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = msgBodyHead + msgBodyHead2 + msgDate + msgGreet + msgBody + msgAdobe + msgAssistance + msgCompliment + msgfooter;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(sendAttachments));

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");
    client.Host = "192.167.89.0";
    client.EnableSsl = false;
    try
    {

        progress();
        client.Send(mail);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ProgressBar1.Visible = false;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Exception excpt = ex;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        while (excpt != null)
        {

            errorMessage += excpt.ToString(); excpt = excpt.InnerException;
            log.Error("Email - LMS Application Error", ex);
            lblError.Text = "There was an error occured while processing your request.\n Please see Event Viewer for more details.";
            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got it, this is what I really want: each recipient should receive only the attachment listed in their record.

Comment: will it work without the foreach loop? sendTo and attachments are arrays.

Comment: i'll try it anyway.. will get back in a minute

Comment: its not working, it only send 1 email with correct attachment but it only reads the last row in the table.

Comment: `sendTo` and `sendAttachments` were the string you were using to iterate through email addresses and attachment paths. I kept the same names for the email address and attachment path you now pass into `sendMail` for minimal editing. You should rename these variables appropriately, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: I didn't change your database query. Check what your query is returning.

Comment: how? I call the method sendMail in the event when I click the send button. where should i place the foreach loop?

Comment: `btnSend_Click` should call `SendMail` for every record returned by your query.

Comment: i have 5 records, still read only the last 1 row, it doesn't send email to all records i have in the database.

Comment: As I said, I didn't change the code that does the database query, and can't debug it for you from here. You're going to have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two loops, one for the list of senders (5) and one for the list of attachments (probably 3), making a total of 15 executions of the code to send the email. I would reorganise your `sendmail` method to something like:

```
foreach (string sendTo in emailList)
{
    // construct email fields ...
    // ...

    foreach (string sendAttachments in attachList)
    {
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(sendAttachments));
    }

    // send email ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Based on your comments to others' answers, it seems you might be getting more than one attachment in your query. You need to debug your code and see exactly what you're getting back from the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've got the call to `client.Send(mail);` inside your attachments foreach loop. It should be outside that loop.

try changing the  `sendMail` method to this:

```
private void sendMail()
{
    string from = "myemail@email.com";
    foreach (string sendTo in emailList)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(sendTo);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "Company Name'", Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = msgBodyHead + msgBodyHead2 + msgDate + msgGreet + msgBody + msgAdobe + msgAssistance + msgCompliment + msgfooter;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        foreach (string sendAttachments in attachList)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(sendAttachments));
        }

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");
        client.Host = "192.167.89.0";
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        try
        {

            progress();
            client.Send(mail);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProgressBar1.Visible = false;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Exception excpt = ex;
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;

            while (excpt != null)
            {

                errorMessage += excpt.ToString(); excpt = excpt.InnerException;
                log.Error("Email - LMS Application Error", ex);
                lblError.Text = "There was an error occured while processing your request.\n Please see Event Viewer for more details.";
                lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and now i receive 5 emails, but the thing is the attachments are all attached in the email. My problem is each recipient should receive only the attachment listed in their record.  example if sample@email.com has an attacment of 1.pdf, he should receive 1.pdf only, other files are not attached.

Comment: @Dhenn Use Ergwun's answer above. It looks good and he beat me to it

Comment: He removes the foreach loop, its working but it only send 1 email with attachment..

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void sendMail()
        {

            string from="myemail@email.com";
            foreach (string sendTo in emailList)
            {

                foreach (string sendAttachments in attachList)
                {
```

You are iterating over `attachList`, but I see nothing in this loop to restrict `attachList` to attachments intended only for the recipient `sendTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why do you need that array lists and loops in SendMail method, maybe something like this :

```
  /// ...snip
  email = getEmail.GetString(0);
  attachment = getEmail.GetString(1);
  SendOneMail(email, attachment);
  /// ... snip


  private void SendOneMail(string email, string attach)
  {
    /// send yust one mail
  }
```